# How can I use python to write a dxf file from coordinates?

Tags: python, ezdxf

I am trying to use ezdxf to write a dxf file from a list of coordinates.

I am able to create a dxf file with a simple line drawn using the code below:

```
import ezdxf
doc = ezdxf.new('R2010') # create a new DXF drawing in R2010 fromat 

msp = doc.modelspace() # add new entities to the modelspace
msp.add_line((0, 0), (10, 0)) # add a LINE entity
doc.saveas('test_line.dxf')
```

For the files that I am working with, there is also a "Z" coordinate, which I do not know how to pass in based on what I have seen in the docs. I also want to pass in hundreds of coordinates in not just a single line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
import ezdxf
doc = ezdxf.new('R2010') # create a new DXF drawing in R2010 fromat 

msp = doc.modelspace() # add new entities to the modelspace
lines = [(0, 0, 0), (10, 0, 0)], [(0, 0, 0), (20, 0, 0)],
for line in lines:
    start = line[0]
    end = line[1]
    msp.add_line(start, end) # add a LINE entity
doc.saveas('test_line.dxf')
```

It includes de Z-axis and add several lines to the file.